# I am trying to find a short story about an experience machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am trying to remember a story that I heard in high school (around 1992) about a guy who visits a man in a shack in the middle of a wasteland because he can give the guy any experience that he wants. He declines, and goes home to his lovely house and wonderful family returning to his fantastic job. He then wakes up in the shack with the man, and leaves.

I would like to use it in my English degree, but I don't know who wrote it, what book it appears in or anything... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I remember this. The shack was in a post-apocalyptic swamp or bayou(?). The machine wasn't a virtual reality machine (as advertised) but was, in fact a multiverse-hopping device that allowed you to access a reality where your fantasies (usually sexual?) could come true. The hero turned out to just have a fantasy of having his dead wife and kids back. The customers always left with a smile on their faces but I recall he left suicidal.

Comment: There may have been some kind of conversation about the price being whatever he had on him?

Comment: Sounds like a mashup of Total Recall (original) and The Giver... with some small variance.

Comment: @Rick I remember this, too! It was some old short stories collection. Robert Scheckley, maybe? I'll try to find this out.

Answer (score 13):

As @EikePierstoff and @Kao have both mentioned, this is almost certainly "The Store of the Worlds" by Robert Sheckley and collected in his short-fiction anthology [of the same name](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12455877-store-of-the-worlds)

You can read (some of it) online [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6jS0PYWOGxIC&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=%22the%20store%20of%20the%20worlds%22&source=bl&ots=kXuRQiLRLv&sig=RGympQJPxO3bj-_QjtbyDdpsqTg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=aBDpU-q0IenE7AaKlYGQDg&ved=0CH0Q6AEwDw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20store%20of%20the%20worlds%22&f=false);

> *Mr. Wayne came to the end of the long, shoulder-high mound of grey
>   rubble, and there was the Store of the Worlds.  It was exactly as his
>   friends had described: a small shack constructed of bits of lumber,
>   parts of cars, a piece of galvanised iron and a few rows of crumbling
>   bricks, all daubed over with a watery blue paint.*
>
> *“I’ve heard about your store from friends,” Mr. Wayne said. “Then you
>   know my price,” Tompkins said.  “Have you brought it?” “Yes,” said Mr.
>   Wayne, holding up his parcel.  “But I want to ask first –” “They
>   always want to ask,” Tompkins said to the parrot, who blinked.  “Go
>   ahead, ask.” “I want to know what really happens.” Tompkins sighed. 
>   “What happens is this.  You pay me my fee.  I give you an injection
>   which knocks you out.  Then, with the aid of certain gadgets which I
>   have in the back of the store, I liberate your mind.”*
>
> *“Your mind, liberated from its body, is able to choose from the
>   countless probability-worlds which the Earth casts off in every second
>   of its existence.”*

The device is able to transfer the mind to an alternate reality for precisely one year, at the cost of ten years of the user's life.

> *If you have been harbouring a secret dream of murder –” “Oh hardly, hardly!” cried Mr. Wayne. “– then you will go to a world where you can
>   murder, where you can roll in blood, where you can outdo de Sade or
>   Caesar, or whoever your idol may be.  Suppose it’s power you want? 
>   Then you’ll choose a world where you are a god, literally and
>   actually.  A bloodthirsty Juggernaut, perhaps, or an all-wise Buddha.”
>   “I doubt very much if I –” “There are other desires, too,” Tompkins
>   said.  “All heavens and all hells.  Unbridled sexuality.  Gluttony,
>   drunkenness, love, fame – anything you want.”*

Comment: Yes, that sounds very much like it! Thanks guys! Hmmm, a lot darker than I remember it - but then that was over 20 years ago, by my reckoning...!

Comment: @Ginjirou - I knew I knew it. Yes, the ending is a bit of a http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuddendownerEnding

Answer (score 8):

Robert Sheckley's "The Store of the Worlds" matches that description (it's four or five pages, so the question already contains all essential plot points),

Comment: Can you indicate why you think this is the right answer?