# Short-story where a man seeks a serum to dream of life before the atomic bomb

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a story, I think 60s / 70s but I'm not sure.

A man learned of a doctor who injects a serum that allows you to dream everything you want, so he goes to this doctor to find out. Then he returns home, where he lives a few days of banal normality: he scolds the children who are arguing, helps his wife do the cleaning, makes small repairs in the house, takes a trip to the lake with the family where a series of mishaps happen anyway, etc.

After he wakes up from the dream, he thanks the doctor who injected him with the serum, and traversing piles of rubble with the help of a geiger counter to find the least radioactive path he returns to the basement where he lives alone.

Comment: Probably the same as this question (with no accepted answer): https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65378/i-am-trying-to-find-a-short-story-about-an-experience-machine/65432#65432

Comment: Our policy is to close story-id questions with the same answer as Duplicates, so I have done so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is most likely Sheckley's "[The store of the worlds](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?383619)". Matches all points (I am also pretty sure this is a duplicate).

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107604/searching-for-a-story-about-a-man-who-passes-a-shop-promising-to-take-him-to-a-m?noredirect=1&lq=1